# moving upper div to down and down div to ip for small devices in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a simple web page and it has a little problem in my small devices. So i need to set position  on these 2 divs.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="right" id="center">
            <img src="img/Golden-One-Page-Web-Template_40.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="left" id="center">
            <h4>february 2014<br/>Our Triumph</h4>
            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure<br/>digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit<br/>aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin<br/>iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni<br/>ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End row-->
```

so i need to move this `left` div to above and that `right` div to below in small devices on bootstrap 3 if anybody ave an idea about this please give me an proper and clean answer

thank you

Comment: I count 5 divs there. Not 2. Also, a couple of things need to be noted: (a) elements shouldn't have the same id's. (b) you should need to be placing 'br' tags throughout paragraphs (set them to bounds of div if wanted) (C) could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate?

Comment: @jbutler483 see the description i have mentioned the classes called left and righ

Comment: i'm using bootstrap please show me an example in bootstrap 3

Comment: somthing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m34gfowu/) or [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/9/) Or vertically see [this](http://biostall.com/demos/swap-and-reorder-divs-smoothly-using-jquery/)

Comment: Please add the twitter-bootstrap tag to this question so that people looking at it know you are using this framework.

Comment: @Celmar's answer is a good answer, always remember to design for mobile first in bootstrap, that's how it is designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Twitter Bootstrap, you can use their push and pull classes to get the effect you want. Start with the mobile layout first and then push and pull the elements at the higher breakpoints.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-7">
        <div class="left" id="center">
            <h4>february 2014<br>Our Triumph</h4>
            <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure<br>digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit<br>aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin<br>iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni<br>ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-md-pull-5">
        <div class="right" id="center">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End row-->
```

Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/BKR9irhYSy

More info about pushing and pulling can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering